# Plot pdf and cdf in histogram by reading csv file

Tags: python, scipy, google-colaboratory

So I want to plot the pfd and cdf in a histogram by reading a csv data. This code below that I wrote in Google Colab to plot pdf and cdf, but not by reading from a csv file. Any idea how? Thanks!

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm

samples=np.random.normal(size=10)
bins=np.arange(-4,5)
bins
print(samples)

histogram=np.histogram(samples,bins=bins,density=True)[0]
bins=0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])
bins
print(histogram)

from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(bins) 
cdf = stats.norm.cdf(bins)
plt.plot(bins, histogram) 
plt.plot(bins, pdf)
plt.plot(bins, cdf)

#This is to read the csv file
data = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/brain_size.csv', delimiter=';', na_values=".")
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is. You read the data with the last line, why don't you use it instead of `samples` to build the histograms?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't get it, how can I replace the samples with data that I read from csv. When i just replace sample with data, it gave me an error. @Botond

Comment: what kind of error? What does your data look like (`data.head()`)? Have you tried using just the corresponding column of `data`?